# Периодичное выполнение JobService не работает

Tags: java, android, jobscheduler

Не вижу смысла что-то объяснять, потому что код довольно простой. Почему не работает периодическое выполнение `MyJobService`?

**MainActivity:**

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MyJobService.scheduleJob(this);
    }
}
```

**MyJobService:**

```java
public class MyJobService extends JobService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyJobService";

    private static final int JOB_ID = 12345;

    public static void scheduleJob(Context context) {
        ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(context, MyJobService.class);
        JobInfo jobInfo
                = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID, serviceComponent)
                .setPeriodic(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5))
                .build();
        JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        if (jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo) == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS)
            Log.i(TAG, "scheduleJob: success");
        else
            Log.i(TAG, "scheduleJob: failure");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        Log.i(TAG, "MyJobService started");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Манифест:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.petr.testjobservice" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestJobService" >

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyJobService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

Если заменить `.setPeriodic(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5))` на `.setMinimumLatency(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2)) .setOverrideDeadline(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5))`, то `MyJobService` успешно однократно отработает.

В обоих случаях `jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo)` возвращает `RESULT_SUCCESS`.

Comment: `schedule` возвращает значение `RESULT_SUCCESS` или `RESULT_FAILURE`, которое необходимо проверять. Возможно `ComponentName` формируется неверно

Comment: @user7860670 дополнил вопрос.